# NVME drive is inaccessible but works after restarting

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop, nvme

I upgraded my laptop's (Asus G751JT) Samsung(OEM) NVME with a kingston A2000. Now In two days in a row I encountered drive inaccessible error couple times, during which the Hard drive appeared to be empty and security tab wasn't available, then restarting the PC solved it!

The first time this happened is on my first PC restart after I initialized the drive, then it worked after that, no solution was attempted.

The second time this happened was after I renamed my windows 10 user profile

I never had any issue before when Samsung was installed

Any Idea whether I should be concerned?

I mean I am not sure whether the cause of this is because of my actions or the hard drive fault or compatibility issue

And FYI the laptop came with NVME slot, I didn't install it

Comment: How old is the drive? Is Samsung magician compatible with the drive?

Comment: it's a new Kingston drive, as for Samsung magician, it can read it, I can see firmware information and it says its its connected to PCIe Gen 2 X 4, microsoft driver, this is the first time I use samsung magician

Comment: I glazed over the fact you replaced the Samsung drive with a Kingston. Without benchmarks comparing the drive I have no other suggestions. Was obviously leaning towards the age of the device being the problem

Comment: Make sure you have the latest firmware installed on the kingston A2000.